# How do I call function from other function?

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code below that I'm having trouble with. I'm trying to call the function that's created inside function().

HTML

```
<html>
<form>
    <input id="schedtxt" type="number" min="0" step="1" />
    <input id="schedSubmit" type="button" value="Submit!" onclick="time(schedtxt)"
</form>
</html>
<style>
```

and the JS

```
var schedText = document.getElementById("schedtxt").value;

function time(schedText) {
        alert("You have entered "+ schedText.value + " seconds");
        UpdateUser(schedText.value);
}

(function(){
//lotsa var here
    function UpdateUser(stuff) {
        //some stuff
    });
    }
}
```

I have try created the time function inside function() but the console says time() is not declared, is there anything I've done wrong?

Comment: That's a local variable.  It doesn't exist outside its function.

Comment: You can bind it to global or window objects

Comment: That is because when you create `time` inside the `(function(){})`, it become local to that scope and won't be accessible from the global scope(it is where the function is searched for  in your inline handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instantiate a variable outside that scope and attribute the function to that variable. It could be something like this:

```js
var schedText = document.getElementById("schedtxt").value;

// Instantianting the variable outside the scope
var UpdateUser;

function time(schedText) {
    alert("You have entered "+ schedText.value + " seconds");
    UpdateUser(schedText.value);
}

(function() {
    //lotsa var here

    UpdateUser = function (stuff) {
        //some stuff
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UpdateUser` function is scoped to the `function()`.  You need it outside that scope so its accessible to the `time` function.

Change your javascript thusly:

```
var schedText = document.getElementById("schedtxt").value;

function time(schedText) {
        alert("You have entered "+ schedText.value + " seconds");
        UpdateUser(schedText.value);
}


function UpdateUser(stuff) {
        //some stuff
    })

(function(){
//lotsa var here

    }
)
```

Comment: Is there any other way around? I prefer everything is kept inside (function(){}), including time function.

Comment: Its just a matter of scope.  If you want it all in that function scope then define `time` within the same scope.  Do some research on "javascript scope" for more information.

Comment: Thanks, definitely need to read more on this. Anyway, out of topic why does `function myfunc(){}` differs than the `(function(){})` ? The parentheses signifies something?